# Java Maven - Unit test run twice?

Tags: java, maven

Small question regarding Maven and running unit test please.

I have a very basic Java SpringBoot project, with some unit tests.
I run the basic `mvn clean install` very straightforward.
For some reason I do not understand, I am seeing all of my unit tests run twice.

one time here:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running MyTest
```

and one time here:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (integration-test) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running MyTest
```

And here is my maven:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <reportsDirectory>target/reports/junit</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

May I ask what did I do wrong, as I do not want unit tests to run twice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Surefire and Failsafe plugins are very similar, and the primary distinction is the phase that they run in. Generally, Surefire runs during the `test` phase and Failsafe runs during the `integration-test` phase. (The default configuration has them looking for slightly different test names, such as `*Test` vs. `*IT`, to know when to run each.)

You have explicitly told Surefire (the unit-test plugin) to run during integration testing. If you don't want this, simply remove the entire `executions` stanza. I also strongly recommend against telling Maven not to fail when the tests fail, and changing the report directory is simply likely to confuse tools like CI that are looking in the default location. Best? Take out the plugin definition entirely and use the defaults.

Comment: what is a "stanza"?